# If they hadith says there are seven styles, why do people say there are 10 qiraat or such?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation

I need clarity in 7 qiraat of the Quran. According to the hadeeth of Ibn ‘Abbaas who narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Jibreel taught me one style and I reviewed it until he taught me more, and I kept asking him for more and he gave me more until finally there were seven styles.”
(narrated by al-Bukhaari, 3047; Muslim, 819), there are only seven styles, so why do people say there 10 qiraats? What is the difference between "style" and "qira'a"? and I think even the seven qiraat ('Assim, Naafi', Ibn Kathir, etc) each of them has 2 readings (Shu'ab 'an 'Assim, Hafs 'an 'Assim, etc). How can these be explained when the hadith says there are only 7 styles?

Comment: These are two different topics which you are mixing.

Comment: Brother please explain

Comment: Check any my answers under the [tag:qiraat]-tag and you'll be enlightened.

Comment: Brother do you know german?

Comment: Yes, why are you asking?

Comment: You know my videos? May Allah increase our iman, I need someone to translate them. Not the Qur'an, but the description and some other things (such as qari's name, names of the rewaya and etc). If interested, tell me and in shaa Allah I will send a text document with all the things I need translated.